# How do I find$ P(X > 2Y)$?

Tags: probability, integration

> Consider the following bivariate pdf for random variables $X$ and $Y$:
>
> $$f_{X,Y}(x,y) = \begin{cases} \tfrac 52(x^2+y) & , 0\leq x\leq 1, 0\leq y \leq 1-x^2\\ 0 & , \textsf{elsewhere}\end{cases}$$
>
> a) Find the marginal pdf of $Y$.
>
> b) Find $\mathsf E(X\mid Y=1/2)$
>
> c) Find $\mathsf E(XY)$
>
> d) Find $\mathsf P(X>2Y)$

I'm specifically referring to part (**d**) of this question [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b53Ds.jpg). I'm having trouble setting up the bounds for the area. I have that the $x$ varies from $2y$ to $\sqrt{1-y}$, and that $y$ varies from $0$ to the intersection of the lines $y=(1/2)x$ and $y= 1-x^{2}$. But this gives a messy number. Where am I going wrong?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Which part are you having trouble with??

Comment: @Upstart Setting up the boundaries. Was I correct?

Comment: $P(Y\lt X/2)=\int_0^1\int_0^{x/2}f_{X,Y}(x,y)dydx $

Comment: @user2034 : your regions look good.  Yes, it looks like the intersection of those two curves is at an irrational number $x$.

Comment: @Michael Thanks! Someone told me my outer bounds should be 0 to 1 instead of what I had so I wasn't sure. Are Upstarts bounds also correct?

Comment: it depends on the order of integration

Comment: The Upstart integral is generic and only partially considers the region over which the PDF is nonzero. If I interpret your integration correctly, it is $$\int_{y=0}^{y_{int}}\int_{x=2y}^{\sqrt{1-y}}\frac{5}{2}(x^2+y)dydx$$ which is over an "almost triangular region" with a flat base, a linear left-edge, and a curvy right-edge.

Comment: As Boris suggests, you could also do an integral of the form $$\int_{x=0}^{x_{int}} \int_{y=0}^{x/2} + \int_{x=x_{int}}^1 \int_{y=0}^{1-x^2}$$.

Comment: @Michael yes that's the region I had in mind, and why I also thought Upstarts bounds weren't completely correct. What exactly do you mean by x_int and y_int?

Comment: Well, you should know what $x_{int}$ and $y_{int}$ are.

Comment: @Michael ah yes of course. Now I know

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sketching the graph of $y=1-x^2$ and $y=x/2$ shows you need to integrate

$$\mathsf P(X>2Y) = \int_0^{(\surd 17-1)/8}\int_{2y}^{\surd(1-y)}\tfrac 52 (x^2+y)\operatorname d x\operatorname d y$$

Or alternatively
$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(Y<X/2) ~= & ~ \int_0^{(\surd 17 - 1)/4}\int_0^{x/2} \tfrac 52 (x^2+y)\operatorname d y\operatorname d x + \int_{(\surd 17-1)/4}^1\int_0^{1-x^2}\tfrac 52(x^2+y)\operatorname dy\operatorname dx \\[2ex]  = & ~ 1-\int_0^{(\surd17-1)/4}\int_{x/2}^{1-x^2} \tfrac 52(x^2+y)\operatorname d y\operatorname d x\end{align}$$

Comment: The intercept point is $(\frac{\surd 17 -1}{4} \raise{0.5ex}, \frac{\surd 17 -1}{8})$.

Comment: Oh you're right it is - Thanks!!

Comment: The answer turns out to be $(2015-411\sqrt{17})/1536\approx 0.2086$.